# Incremental Server Emits

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I have just hooked a MySQL database to my node.js server for a game I am working on. To test that there is communication between the client, server, and db I set up some functions to simulate someone logging into the game. Communication works, but some strange behavior is also observed. Each time the log in button is clicked a loginAttempt message is emitted to the server from the client. The credentials are then checked to see if they are valid. A loginSuccess message is then sent back to the client with a true or false data representing success or failing. The bizarre behavior begins here, where the client seems to receive an additional message for each sequential call. The code is displayed below with a corresponding log output for 3 failed attempts and 1 successful attempt. 
Client code:

```
function logIn(user, pass) {
    socket.emit("loginAttempt", user, pass);
    console.log("1");

    socket.on("loginSuccess", function (data) {
        console.log("2");
        if (data === true) {
            console.log("3");
            socket.emit("loginSuccess");
            $("body").empty();
            $("body").load("game.html");
        }
        else {
            console.log("4");
            socket.emit("loginFail");
        }
    });
}
```

where `socket` is socket.io variable connecting to the server
Server Code:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
console.log("User has connected");

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error connecting to database: " + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log("Connected to database");
});

socket.on("disconnect", function (socket) {
    connection.end();
    console.log("User has disconnected.");
});

socket.on("loginAttempt", function (username, password) {
    console.log("1");
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'", function (err, rows, fields) {
        console.log("2");
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            if (rows.length === 0) {
                socket.emit("loginSuccess", false);
                console.log("3");
            }
            else {
                socket.emit("loginSuccess", true);
                console.log("4");
            }
        }
    });
});

socket.on("loginSuccess", function () {
    console.log("Login Successful!")
});

socket.on("loginFail", function () { 
    console.log("Login Fail!");
});
});
```

where `connection` is variable used to connect to the db
Client Output:

```
1 //Attempt 1
2
4
1 //Attempt 2
2
4
2
4
1 //Attempt 3
2
4
2
4
2
4
1 //Attempt 4
2
3
2
3
2
3
2
3
```

The numbers are represenatative of different portions of the code being executed, as can be seen.
Server Output:

```
User has connected
Connected to database
1
2
3
Login Fail!
1
2
3
Login Fail!
Login Fail!
1
2
3
Login Fail!
Login Fail!
Login Fail!
1
2
4
Login Successful!
Login Successful!
Login Successful!
Login Successful!
```

I considered this being an issue of reconnecting to the server every click and the client then acting as many clients, but if that was the case I would expect there to be multiple "User has connected" logs. It seems to be the client receiving incremental `loginSuccessful, data` messages, but I cannot see why this would be occurring since the server code emitting this message only runs once. Right now I'm at a loss of why this is occurring or what may be causing it.

Comment: you call  `socket.emit("loginSuccess");` from inside the loginSuccess event, triggering itself without passing true

Comment: I do, that should be sent to the server if it's a successful login, and is only sent in the last attempt of the example above. Even if this some how back triggered to be received on the end being sent from, the client, this would only be possible behavior on the last attempt which emits that message

Comment: yes, but `emit()` doesn't just raise the `loginSuccess` event on the server, it also raises it on the client with no event arg, which then causes the "Login Fail!" message to appear (on the client only, not the server)... use a different event name to send it to the server see what i mean, like a 'clientLoginSuccess' event that is only handled by the server. there might be a command like `emit()` that would not raise locally, check into it.

Comment: I just changed the client `emit(loginSuccess)` to `emit(loginGood)`, having the server listen for loginGood instead. Running the same test as above, I received the exact same outputs on both client and server. The problem with this, even if it was the cause here, is the "Login Fail!" log occurs from a `loginFail` message, not a `loginSuccess` message. The loginSuccess message isn't sent until the fourth and final attempt, which is successful, but displays the same behavior as the three fails prior

Comment: as fas as getting one extra each click, that's because you subscribe to future messages in your login function, but you never unsubscribe. you probably don't want to bind any events from inside another event, unless you cleanup potential dupes before you bind.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "subscribe to future events." Could you possibly cite a line of code or location? This sounds like my issue but I'm not sure where or how what you're describing is happening

Comment: `socket.on` works the same as `$.on` in that it subscribes to future events. each time you call `logIn()`, you subscribe a handler to any _loginSuccess_ that may arrive over the socket (not just the next time, but all times) . you likely just need to move `socket.on("loginSuccess", function (data) { ...` outside of the `logIn()` function, so your socket is not getting over-subscribed.

Comment: I want to thank you for solving my problem. It was being subscribed and moving that code block out solved the problem. I had tried doing that before but was having an error show along the lines of _cannot use "on" of undefined_, which happened because I had socket be global but defined when the document loaded. Having move that out of the `$(document).ready` function it is now defined and working. A last question of mine is, will connecting the socket to the server before the document loads cause any issues? In hindsight I can't think of any, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: cheers. as long as you can hit any CSS selectors used by socket-based events, you need not wait until the entire doc is loaded. it looks like yuou only use `$("body")`, so as long as you link to that JS from the <body> tag, you'll be fine.